# How doesn't the font-family work here?

Tags: html, css, font-family

I tried this:

```
div.content
{
    font-family: Verdana;
}
```

and this:

```
div.content
{
    font-family: 'Verdana';
}
```

and this:

```
#view
{
 /* other stuff */
 font-family: Verdana;
}
```

for this simple html:

```
<div id="view">
  asdas AHGAUHGAS
  <!-- some other stuff -->
</div>
```

And it doesn't work...

I also tried with like 15 different fonts (in case some of them are not available in my IDE or whatever)... still no effect.

[**UPDATE: jsfiddle for the ones who want it**](http://jsfiddle.net/eKxAv/)

Comment: create us some jsfiddle please

Comment: Did you realize? the fiddle which you posted above is working fine.

Comment: @Mr_Green - yes I realized that, which made me wonder even more. The problem fixed when I added `..., sans-serif;`. And I don't know why is it required in order for the fonts to work in my case.

Comment: _The font-family CSS property allows for a prioritized list of font family names_. Check [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-family) for more info.

Comment: Are you sure it's not rendering the sans-serif now? It sounds like you may not have Verdana installed on your computer or it's installed under a different name. Try using Firebug to see which font is actually being computed in the browser.

Comment: @Coop, Firebug only shows the computed value of `font-family` (which may well be `Verdana` even when Verdana does not exist in the system). To see the actual font used by the browser, use the Font Information add-on to Firefox.

Comment: The question is obscure, the jsfiddle does not correspond to the text of the question, there seems to be a misunderstanding of what `div.content` means, and in the case of using a correct selector `#view`, the problem is most probably in some code outside the snippet included in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;` see how that works.

Also post a JSfiddle so people here can have a play about with your code.

Comment: Yep, this worked. But I don't understand why ?! When I have the `..., sans-serif;` it's fine. Without it - there's no change in whatever font I put.

Comment: I guess It's like trying to play a CD without a CD player :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a `div.content` in your HTML there so that won't do anything.

Check you actually have the Verdana font installed on your computer then try this:

```
#view { font-family: 'Verdana' !important; }
```

Also, slightly unrelated but you're using CSS comment tags in HTML.

Answer (score -1):

First u have "Verdana" font family in your PC. Check your system.

Comment: The OP did say he'd tried 15 different fonts in case this was the issue so this clearly isn't the answer.

Answer (score -2):

Don't know where is the error:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #view{font-family:"Verdana", Geneva, sans-serif;} 
    #view{font-family:"Verdana";}
    #view{font-family:Verdana;}
</style>
```

You can use any one CSS to show the Font-Family.